# Suppose $G$ and $H$ are two countably infinite abelian groups s.t. every nontrivial element of $G\times H$ has order $7$. Then $G\cong H$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, direct-product, infinite-groups

Suppose $G$ and $H$ are two countably infinite abelian groups such that every nontrivial element of $G \times H$ has order $7$. Then $G$ is isomorphic to $H$.

My idea is that each non-trivial element of $G$ and $H$ has order $7$. Therefore, we can consider them as vector spaces over ${\mathbb{Z}}/{7\mathbb{Z}}$. Since their order is the same, their dimension over $\mathbb{Z}/7{\mathbb{Z}}$ will also be the same. This implies that they are isomorphic as vector spaces and hence isomorphic as groups.

Is my approach correct? Is there any other way to prove this ?

Comment: "their order is the same", why?  You didn't say that.

Comment: Should I write their ''cardinality''?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @iateawalrus No, not every vector space is a ring. We just need to define the multiplication of a scalar of the underlying field and a vector such that it satisfies certain axioms. In this case the multiplication is $p.v = v^p$ or simply $p.v$ if we denote the group operation as addition.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh sorry. I have updated the question.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Actually it does. Since the cardinalities are countably infinte, dimenesion of each of them over the field will be countably infinite. And then it follows from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176626/let-v-w-be-two-countably-infinite-dimensional-vector-space-over-the-same-field)

Comment: @MartinArgerami Actually this result must hold for uncountable dimension also. Is there any counterexample in your mind ?

Comment: Fair enough , I misread.